# Store ruby Mail (from gem) object in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, activerecord, imap, gmail-imap

I'm currently implementing a very basic IMAP client into an application I'm building in Rails. I'm using the Mail gem which supplies lots of useful ways of parsing the imap data.

I'd like to store the Mail object that it's generating in the database. Is that possible?

i.e.

```
   email = Email.new
   email.uid = id 
   email.mail = Mail.new(imap.fetch(id, "RFC822")[0]["attr"]["RFC822"]
   email.save
```

It's a convenience thing where I don't want to have to download the object again unless I have to since performance on the IMAP call is slow, but I'd like to be able to have it there to look back on (and do any breaking down I needed to later).

I could then call

```
   email.find(x).mail.body
```

and various other useful things without having to build out that functionality in my own email model.

Q1: How would I set up the active record model?

Q1a: Would I be better off doing something that excluded the attachments to make it an easier object to store? (is that even possible?)

Appreciate your help,

Comment: I should probably clarify the question here.
I'm actually asking if I can just store the object in a database field. i.e. when I retrieve the field I get the object, which I can then do things with.
I want to avoid having to set up a full database schema for emails every time I store one.

Answer (score 0):

Several database schemata have been developed to store mail. I've worked on [one,](http://aox.org/schema) and there are others. Believe me, it's hard work. The result can be very useful, but since your question doesn't focus on the result I suspect it's not worthwhile in your case.

You might find it easier to use a json library to write your object graph to a file with an automatically inferred structure, as most json libraries seem to support these days. That won't let you do as much, but it's *very* much easier and lets you store both completely and incompletely retrieved messages. If you haven't fetched a particular body part, the json library will just write a null for that field.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the stored mails. If you need only specific parts of the mail to be easily accessible trough the database you won't need a complex setup like archiveopteryx, which basically maps a complete representation of emails to relational database tables. In most cases though you won't need that much detail and it will be totally perfect to use a simple data model.

A1: `rails g model Email from to subject date:datetime message_id body`. this are just the basic parts, should get you started.

A1a: You don't need to store the attachments if you don't want to. If you need them, you'll probably be better off not storing them in the database itself. Attachments are just like uploads so there are plenty of gems that can help you do that (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads).

Comment: I'm not really looking to break up the object. I'm happy to store it as is, then do whatever I'm doing in the controller. 
Obviously I could extract every piece of information piece by piece, but Mail gem seems a much more convenient way of doing that. 
i.e. Store the object in the db. Then, should I ever need to go back to it, I can always retrieve the entire object. If I take pieces then I'll lose the rest of it.

Comment: Databases are good to find items based on their properties. If you don't need that, just want to store the mails somewhere for easier access to the raw data, I would prefer a simple file storage instead of wasting any database resources.

Comment: I know that it's been years since the question, but this came up in my search and I thought I should mention this for anyone who happens to find their way here as well.

https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/238#issuecomment-12744520

If you just want to store the mail itself (no parsing etc) you can do what one of the mail gem collaborators suggest:

> just use `encoded = mail.encoded` and deserialize use `Mail.new(encoded)`

So you save the encoded mail in the db (plaintext most likely) and to deserialize, just instantiate a Mail object with the encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

Using posgres jsonb columns, you can store the email as json, in my case I disregard the attachments (which I store the reference to and retrieve as and when required).
This works pretty well with the Mail gem.